# payment with credit card not working

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

we have implement paypal payment getway to my site.

we are checking with sandbox test mode. Payment by login with paypal account working fine, but without login paypal account using card option payment not working. I am try with test card details it showing this error message "The card you entered cannot be used for this payment. Please enter a different debit or credit card number."

i have user all cardnumber provided by paypal still get error

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#paypal-credit-card-numbers-for-testing

i am also used this still non of card get payment done
https://saijogeorge.com/dummy-credit-card-generator/

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal has some issue with sandbox some time.

I have resolve this problem by using location as US and supply fake address detail of USA .. which is provided by https://www.fakeaddressgenerator.com/World/us_address_generator.

Credit card detail from https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

After provide USA location it works so I hop it work for all who facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue at PayPal end, I am able to reproduce the same error. I will get back to you soon as soon this issue fixes.

Comment: This issue has been fixed. I am able to process the payment without any issues. Please check it.